# Nested forEach in Jade not working

Tags: node.js, foreach, pug

I'm passing multiple employee objects returned from MongoDB to the Jade template. An employee object would look like this:

```
{ entry_time: 2016-03-26 21:05:27.108Z,
  history: [[room1, 2016-03-26 21:05:27.108Z, 2016-03-26 21:05:27.108Z],
             [room2, 2016-03-26 21:05:27.108Z, 2016-03-26 21:05:27.108Z]],
  current_room: 'meeting03',
  last_name: 'B',
  first_name: 'A',
  eid: '3',
  _id: 56c6592005bb4ebfa29b6526 }
```

app.js:

```
app.get('/find', function(req,res){
    return res.render('find', {data: employee});
});
```

Old find.jade:

```
- data.forEach(function(employee){
      - var first_name = employee.first_name
      - var last_name = employee.last_name
      - var current_room = employee.current_room
      - var history = employee.history
      li #{first_name}
      li #{last_name}
      li #{current_room}
      - history.forEach(function(entry) {
               - var room = entry[0]
               - var entry_time = entry[1]
               - var dept_time = entry[2]
      -});
- });
```

The above jade code worked fine until I added a few more li items in the nested forEach function:

New find.jade:

```
- data.forEach(function(employee){
      - var first_name = employee.first_name
      - var last_name = employee.last_name
      - var current_room = employee.current_room
      - var history = employee.history
      li #{first_name}
      li #{last_name}
      li #{current_room}
      - history.forEach(function(entry) {
               - var room = entry[0]
               - var entry_time = entry[1]
               - var dept_time = entry[2]
               li #{room} // I get a warning: missing } 
               li #{entry_time}
               li #{dept_time}
      -}); // another warning: statement expected
- });
```

I have no idea why adding three li elements would break the nested forEach. Any idea how I should fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I changed the nested forEach to this:

```
for entry in history
      - var room = entry[0]
      - var entry_time = entry[1]
      - var dept_time = entry[2]
      li #{room}
      li #{entry_time}
      li #{dept_time}
```

It worked. Hope this would help someone else.